# DPDK built error with GCC for array bounds

Tags: gcc, debian, dpdk

when i install dpdk into my Debian server

`make install T=x86_64-native-linux-gcc`

there will be an error:
`error: array subscript is above array bounds [-Werror=array-bounds]
  rte_mov32((uint8_t *)dst + 2 * 32, (const uint8_t *)src + 2 * 32)`

so, how to solve it, and why it happened to dpdk?
thx!

os: x86_64 GNU/Linux 4.14.52.bm.6-amd64

Gcc version: 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)

DPDK version: 20.05-4c

Error Message:

`In file included from /root/zeh/dpdk/x86_64-native-linux-gcc/include/rte_ether.h:21:0,
from /root/zeh/dpdk/drivers/net/ena/ena_ethdev.c:7:
/root/zeh/dpdk/drivers/net/ena/ena_ethdev.c: 
In function ‘ena_rss_key_fill’:/root/zeh/dpdk/x86_64-native-linux-gcc/include/rte_memcpy.h:343:2: error: array subscript is above array bounds [-Werror=array-bounds]
  rte_mov32((uint8_t *)dst + 2 * 32, (const uint8_t *)src + 2 * 32);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/zeh/dpdk/x86_64-native-linux-gcc/include/rte_memcpy.h:344:2: error: array subscript is above array bounds [-Werror=array-bounds]
  rte_mov32((uint8_t *)dst + 3 * 32, (const uint8_t *)src + 3 * 32);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/zeh/dpdk/drivers/net/ena/ena_ethdev.c: At top level:
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-address-of-packed-member’ [-Werror]`

and i can install success with DPDK-19.11.

Comment: Please add details, like OS version, GCC version, DPDK version, error from compiler, CPU details

Comment: If `drivers/net/ena/` is not your target PMD, can you try disabling `ENA` in `/root/zeh/dpdk/x86_64-native-linux-gcc/.config` and rebuild? Steps to build set `RTE_SDK` and `RTE_TARGET` and cd to RTE_TARGET and run `make -j 10`

Comment: I have solved this problem for allocating too little memory for my vm, but I don't know how to close this question :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: only place where array-bound gets ignored is in `rte_memcpy.h` for

```
 #if (GCC_VERSION >= 90000 && GCC_VERSION < 90400)
 #pragma GCC diagnostic push
 #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Warray-bounds"
 #endif
```

I am able to build for both `make` and `meson` successfully on

DPDK: `dpdk-20.05-rc4`

OS: `4.15.0-99-generic`

gcc: `7.5.0`

TAREGT: `x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc`

Binary: `static and shared`

This looks more like a platform and environment-related issue. Can you open this DPDK `Bugzilla` and share the same `dev@dpdk.org` via http://core.dpdk.org/contribute/? They would have similar setup configured for CI and CD (hence help you better)